# Make a listener to know when a new item is being added to DynamoDB

Tags: android, push-notification, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table with about 5-6 items in it.

In my android app, I want to create a listener which will run in background. The listener's purpose is to detect when a new item is being added to the DynamoDB table remotely, and when it detects a new item in the DB, the app will inform the user about it with a push notification which will include also one of the attributes of the item.

Is it possible? And if it does, then how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you need is the **SNS service** used by an **AWS Lambda** triggered by **DynamoDB streams**, then SNS can send notifications to **Firebase Cloud Messaging** (FCM) that it is connected with your app using a Google library:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

After the setup in your android app with FCM library, you can implement a
[messageReceived listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

Answer (score 1):

you can use aws Lambda function on dynamodb stream

the lambda function get a stream of added/updated/deleted items, and can perform any action.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-ddb.html

Comment: But how can I detect it through the app and to make it to run on the background?

Comment: the lambda function can detect a change in dynamodb table, and perform an action (send push notification for example, or prepare a msg in some queue for you process to read it from there and send push..)

Answer (score -1):

[DynamoDB Triggers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) is what you are looking for. Using triggers, you can configure listeners which could respond to any DynamoDB events.

Comment: But how can I detect it through the app and to make it to run on the background?

Comment: You can use Amazon API Gateway - https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/ for this. You can read more about AWS Lambda - API Gateway usage here : https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/#mobile